# Copy object with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three fields, in html it look likes

```
<input type="text" name="begin" />
<input type="text" name="end" />
<input type="email" name="email" />
```

I want create button, witch will be copy these fields.
If i copy once, i need to show button, witch will be delete last copy object. Please, help me to solve this problem

Comment: Copy these fields mean  Copy value of these fields ?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question better? so that we could understand what do you want exactly?

Comment: I dont find any reference to **object** in your question

Comment: @AkshatG it means i need I need the same fields when i click to the button

Comment: @RayonDabre object means all of these fields

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy please, read the comment below

Comment: @qweqweqweqwe add your `javascript` or `jQuery` code

Answer (score 0):

Pleae take a look in this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ym2rjfaa/

When you press copy it is copied the values to the document.
When you press remove, it will removed the values.

```js
$('#copy').click(function() {
  var begin = $('<div>').html($('[name=begin]').val())
  var end = $('<div>').html($('[name=end]').val())
  var email = $('<div>').html($('[name=email]').val())

  var remove = $('<button>remove</button>')

  $('#copied').append(begin)
  $('#copied').append(end)
  $('#copied').append(email)
  $('#copied').append(remove)

  remove.click(function() {
    begin.add(end).add(email).add(remove).remove()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="begin" />
<input type="text" name="end" />
<input type="email" name="email" />
<button id=copy>Copy</button>
<div id=copied></div>
```